# How do I make the terminal always open in the same place?

Tags: gnome-terminal, 15.04

When I open a terminal, it appears at a seemingly random spot on my desktop. I then move it to where I want it.

How can I either make the terminal appear at the place I last left it, or make it always open at a specific place?

More generally, can this be applied to all applications?

Comment: What you are looking for seems to be this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/613973/how-can-i-start-up-an-application-with-a-pre-defined-window-size-and-position/614205#614205

Comment: Please leave a comment if you manage (or not).

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thank you, I will probably try that, although it does seem complex. I was expecting an answer that pointed me to some setting that I had failed to find.

Comment: Hi Carl, it should really be easy if you do the described steps. You can even easily make shortcuts as quicklist items in your Terminal launcher. I'd be happy to guide you in that. Alternatively, you could make it a keyboard shortcut.