# Saving Desktop display of 4 windows on my screen throughout reboot

Tags: desktop-environments

Every time I log into Ubuntu first thing I do is to open up 4 small Windows on my desktop ( 2 on top and 2 at the bottom).  These are shell windows, so that I could
do work on a window ( like running a program ) and move onto another window to do any other thing I'll like.

So, here is my simple question, How Can I preserve these 4 windows every time I reboot without having to waste time opening them up every time I log into Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance,

Vinnie G.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I start applications automatically on login?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Comment: would this http://askubuntu.com/questions/613973/how-can-i-start-up-an-application-with-a-pre-defined-window-size-and-position/614205#614205 or this http://askubuntu.com/a/621811/72216 be useful to you? Leave a comment if you need to know how to add multiple windows to startup applications exactly.