# Dual monitor problem on Ubuntu 14.04. After monitor switch off and on, application Chrome closes by itself

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, google-chrome, display, hdmi

I have a problem that involves a **Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS** that runs on a **NUC Mini-PC**.The NUC is connected with two external **Samsung Smart TVs**

- 1st display connected via HDMI ,
- 2nd display connected via HDMI (Through an adapter from the MiniDisplay Port of the Mini-PC).

I am using the Monitors(TVs) to present two collections of reports through a webpage interface in two browsers (Chrome), one collection of reports for each TV. Each browser runs on full screen on its own monitor.

I have to mention that I must stick to the Chrome browser due some strict interpretation of some CSS  properties.

My problem is that after I switch off and back on the Samsung TVs, the browser which was opened the first closes by itself, without any user interaction.
Thus user has to open the browser again and drag it manually to its former screen.

Do you have a solution or explanation why this occurs? How can I handle the situation without the need to open manually again the browser and drag it back to the former hosting screen?

Thank you.

Comment: Indeed it is a bit weird. Are you sure that it does not just move on the other screen? You can BTW configure where the window should be opened automatically, so you will "just" have to re-open it and not moving it.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Chrome browser closes and not just moves on the other screen. But anyway, this is good to know: how can i configure where the window should be opened and how to open the browser automatically?

Comment: About automatically re-opening it, I don't know.  For the placement, have a look [at this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/621811/29595)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script (or software) to open an application window on a specific viewport and position](http://askubuntu.com/questions/621721/script-or-software-to-open-an-application-window-on-a-specific-viewport-and-po)