# Open Chrome window browser on different screens

Tags: google-chrome, .desktop

I am new here and not (yet) a Ubuntu experienced user but am working on it. :)

Can anyone help me in following matter.

Working with Ubuntu 16.04 version.
I would like to find a solution to open 3 Chrome browser windows with 3 different url's in kiosk (full screen) mode on 3 different monitors.

I have already tried to get it fixed with browser settings "restart where you left off" but a reboot will generate a browser error in each window.

Auto start Chrome in kiosk mode has been added to the startup folder as a .desktop file, so far it works for 1 window.

Any help will be very hard appreciated.

Comment: Opening windows on either different screens and/or viewports can be done like: http://askubuntu.com/questions/621721/is-there-a-script-or-software-to-open-an-application-window-on-a-specific-view/621811#621811. The `--kiosk` option only works when chrome does not run yet, and then only once.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question, but it can help.
I've heard KDE has better support for multiscreen things. Try Kubuntu, and say something for us.

Comment: Fact remains that `Chrome` only supports opening in kiosk mode when it does not run (yet). The screen thing isn't the issue. (See comment on the question).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, maybe you could have 3 instances of chrome running on each monitor, on full screen mode... But if you really know, I won't argue, as I don't know. Just quoting some info:

"A multi-monitor bliss

Plasma is bliss for those with multiple monitor setups. Plasma gives each monitor a personality of its own - which is quite limited on other DEs. You can give each monitor a different wallpaper (you can actually set different wallpapers for virtual desktops and activities as well.) Each monitor can have its own desktop layout and panels. The widgets on these panels and desktops can be configured differently which means, if you work with clients who are in different time zones, you can change the time of each desktop to that particular time-zone.

No other DE, in my knowledge, is capable of doing that." [https://www.linux.com/learn/how-use-kde-plasma-desktop-pro]

Comment: Thanks for this information.
I have already been working on Kubuntu but encountered performance issues.