# What is overriding my window geometry? (Unity / 15.10)

Tags: unity, window-manager, usability

Out of the box, on a freshly installed Ubuntu 15.10, if I start a terminal, it will launch a window which fills almost the entire screen.  It's not maximized in the window manager sense, but its dimensions are such that it fills the entire screen.

If from this window I launch `gnome-terminal --geometry=80x24` I get a second terminal window which is *also* pseudo-maximized (the output from `resize` tells me 80x31 on my current screen).

What exactly is overriding my `--geometry` argument, and how do I disable it?

My end goal is to have applications launch at whatever dimensions their designers intended, so I am not looking for a fix specifically for `gnome-terminal`.  The list of applications I actually care about is fairly short (Terminal, Emacs, Firefox, Thunderbird, Software Center, settings, etc) but I would like to avoid creating and maintaining a list of per-application "overrides for the override" and just get rid of the thing which does the geometry overriding in the first place.

The workaround at [How can I start up an application with a pre-defined window size and position?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613973/how-can-i-start-up-an-application-with-a-pre-defined-window-size-and-position) is one prime example of the kind of clean-up I would like to avoid; that is the reason I am asking what causes this, rather than just how I can avoid it.

I would like to keep my other settings as much out of the box as possible.  For example, disabling Unity completely will fix this, but also loses window title bars etc.

Requested output:

```
tripleee@vbvntv$ dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/
[legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9]
use-theme-transparency=false

[legacy]
schema-version=uint32 3
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/` to your question and notify me afterwards with a comment, please?

Comment: Not what I expected... :-/

Comment: Just a wild hunch, but what happens if you change or set/unset the default size for the terminal (profile preferences > set custom window size )

Comment: @JacobVlijm Hmmm, the Terminal > Preferences > Profiles tab > Unnamed (current) shows 80x24 in "Initial Terminal Size", but if I create a new named profile with those settings and select it as the default for new windows, `gnome-terminal` creates a new window with the size I indicated in the profile.  Now even after I deleted that profile, this setting is active (because, I guess, the "Unnamed" profile with these settings is now in active use, rather than just a dormant template ... or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

You could check if there is something relevant in environment – by looking at output of command `env` ran in the initial `gnome-terminal`.

Also, file `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop` can have something added in `Exec=` line.

Comment: I am sorry to have to downvote this, but it really amounts to mere speculation.  If you can point to something specific in the `env` output I have pasted at http://dpaste.com/1A27524 I will be happy to remove the downvote.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: That quite hurts. Anyway, I added one other possibility to the answer. PS. The bug doesn't reproduce on my system so I couldn't look at `env`'s output. In yours I don't see anything.

Comment: The `.desktop` file is unremarkable, (`Exec=gnome-terminal`, no options) and would not affect the command-line invocation anyway.