# How to make ubuntu remember a windows position and size? (2 Monitors)

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, compiz

Hi everyone so I decided to change to ubuntu 14.04, although I've had some problems (most of which I was able to fix after researching), while **I know that linux isn't windows**, I want it to save window's positions and sizes. In windows it would save to registry and instantly resize the window in question when it would startup again but in ubuntu it doesn't do that, I've tried to use devilspie and compiz and kde etc but I need something which is automatic like in windows. I need this to be productive.

For example if I move firefox to my 2nd monitor and try to maximize it or use the hot corners (or something) when I close it and reopen it again it will startup on my main monitor. I don't want it to do this.

If ubuntu can't do this is there another distro I could use that has this feature?

Comment: This should be at least helpful, if not be a dupe. Let me know if you managevsnd if you find it to be a soultion. http://askubuntu.com/questions/613973/how-can-i-start-up-an-application-with-a-pre-defined-window-size-and-position/614205#614205 there is no differenc placing it on another screen, it is one and yhe same desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, distributions running the KDE environment can do this... One can set positions for windows based on window class, name etc. It needs some practice though.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)