# How to start X application with specific width an height?

Tags: xorg

I need to start X applications with specific width an height. I didn't find any good solution except using xdotool [xdotool - fake keyboard/mouse input, window management, and more](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool).

Could I just append some arguments after application start command to archive this?

Comment: In general, no. For a particular application, maybe. Consult its manual page or other documentation.

Comment: Many X applications will accept a `-geometry` argument e.g. `xclock -geometry 48x48`: see the `GEOMETRY SPECIFICATIONS` section of the `X` manual page (`man X` or `man 7 X`)

Comment: Right,I used to think the -display is available on all x applications, so there should be some optional arguments to specific width and height for all x applications, now I know this option is -geometry form steeldriver's answer. But sadly, whether a specific application supports this option is uncertain， it depends the developer of application. So I give up this attempt, because it is't available at every time. Thank you very much for your help @fkraiem

Comment: Which window manager do you use? At least with openbox, it maybe possible to specify both dimensions and position.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I start up an application with a pre-defined window size and position?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/613973/how-can-i-start-up-an-application-with-a-pre-defined-window-size-and-position)