# 17.04 How to set default window screen position

Tags: 17.04, window-manager, default

Is it possible to set the default window position when an app is opened/launched from coords 0,0 to something else like:

- (saved) - previously opened coords
- (custom) custom x,y coords
- (default) centered x,y of screen

**What I've done:**
I've modified /org/gtk/settings/file-chooser/window-position to (100,100) as I cannot find any other system setting or option to define windows/apps to open center screen. This doesn't seem to affect anything.

Additionally what used to be at "System Settings > Look and Feel" is no longer present which had an option to choose the default app position as centered.

**I am experiencing 3 scenarios:**

1) Some of my setting dialogs always open center as desired, for example System Settings dialog.

2) Then I have some apps that seem to remember their position/size as desired, for example Chrome, Vivaldi, System Monitor...

3) But others like the file manager, terminal, thunderbird, dconf editor and more all open in the upper left (0,0) coords which places the drag-able title bar just under my top status bar and it is very difficult to grab and re position these windows.

I am trying to fix scenario #3, muchas gracias =)

Comment: Not sure if it is *exactly* what you are looking for, but: https://askubuntu.com/questions/613973/how-can-i-start-up-an-application-with-a-pre-defined-window-size-and-position

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, not into your question.

Comment: Hi thanks @JacobVlijm while an interesting solution to set a window at predefined dimensions centered on screen via script/command line, the answer provided below was very simple and seems to be a one-time fix.  Thx for sharing your find =)

Comment: @Pilot6 Sorry, I was simply referencing the accepted solution below, I'll update the thread.

Comment: @PhilipIngram This is not a forum and this is not a thread. If the answer solved your problem, then accept and upvote it if you can upvote. There is no need to quote the answer in your question.

Comment: @Pilot6, sorry to offend so easily, duly noted.  Thx and updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix scenario #3...

Hold down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key on the keyboard, then left-click-hold-drag the mouse pointer in an open space of the window that's hidden under the top panel. Drag the window to the desired position.

Another solution would be to install `Compiz Config Manager`, and configure the `Place Windows` pane to put the windows where you'd like them permanently.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Comment: While it doesn't "fix" issue 3, it is a great work around to be able to move the window to the desired screen position without too much trouble.  Would be nice to not have to do this at all and remember it's position as in previous builds.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes thank you, I gave you an up vote as the info you provided is very helpful but was told it won't show because my rep here is not high enough yet =(

It has worked excellent moving windows into place each time much easier but no they do not retain position upon next launch.

Comment: Then use Compiz Config Manager. There's a pane there that allows you to specify where you want windows to be placed.

Comment: Update your answer to include this info and I'll accept it as the solution. Upon installing compiz config settings manager I was able to enable Window Management > Place Windows and the within that setting also set General > Workarounds (enabled) and Placement Mode to centered.

Comment: @PhilipIngram done. Thanks! Glad you got it set to your desire.