# How to position windows with compizconfig-settings-manager

Tags: windows, compiz, configure, location

At boot/login two apps are launched in my system, and I need to control their positions on the screen.

I have installed [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/x11/compizconfig-settings-manager) and found the Place Window option. But there my ignorance is too great to continue.

I have searched here, but unfortunately the tips and hints stop about where I also end up. [17.04 How to set default window screen position](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930131/17-04-how-to-set-default-window-screen-position) is a typical example.

My questions:
1. Which of the three alternatives should I use?
2. How do I define which window I want to position?
3. How do I calculate X and Y coordinates? Is (0,0) the upper left? How calculate coordinates for a window to be positioned in the lower right of my screen?

The reason for this three-fold question is the delicasy of my system; I dare not use trail-and-error on it.

Comment: house rules ask folks to limit the scope of a question; asking for three things in a question is daunting, and often that's the find of question folks don't invest their (volunteer) time in answering. How about breaking this down into three questions by clicking on [edit], removing two questions, and then making them into questions of their own?

Comment: And by "At boot/login two applications/windows are launched" do you mean you've set two applications to run via autostart?

Comment: And read up about *xwininfo* and *wmctrl* including `wmctrl -lG`.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask  What types of questions should I avoid asking? ...Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Comment: At boot or login two applications are autostarted.

Comment: xwininfo and wmctrl will give the information needed for calculating wanted x and y coordinates for the windows in question,possibly also answering question 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a thread on [LinuxQuestions.org, Fixed Windows Placemnet Using CompizConfig](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/fixed-window-placement-using-compizconfig-4175553586/) I found a working howto. See the question by CVAlkan. It answered all my questions.

Answer (score 0):

3. .

A) *How do I calculate X and Y coordinates?*
Start from 0,0 (upper left) and move the desire number of pixels across for the first starting coordinate, then down for the second starting coordinate.

B) *Is (0,0) the upper left?*
Yes.

C) *How (to) calculate coordinates for a window to be positioned in the lower right of my screen?*
Your screen resolution minus one is the bottom right; if your screen is set to 1920x1280 then bottom right is (1919,1279). Subtract the size of the desired window from that value for the start coordinates; for example, if you want a 320x180 window positioned at bottom right, it would start at ((1919-320),(1279-180)) or (1599,1099). Don't forget, if you use a bottom panel, to offset for its height as well.

Comment: This answer is what I needed for understanding the screen -coordinate system. Thanks.