# Compiz: Fixed window placement, which alternative?

Tags: compiz, configuration, window, location

I configured my Ubuntu 16.04 system to open two windows automatically at login.

For the purpose of fixed location of these, I am trying *CompizConfiguration Settings Manager*, function *Place Windows*. The *Fixed Windows Placement* tab gives me three choices:

- Windows with fixed position
- Windows with fixed placement mode
- Windows with fixed viewport

How are these alternatives to be used? I have tried to find an explanation, but failed. Any light on the matter is gratefully received.

See also [How to position windows with compizconfig-settings-manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179749/how-to-position-windows-with-compizconfig-settings-manager)