# Remove white blinking cursor for only one terminal - bash Script

Tags: command-line, bash

Lately I have been researching for a way that I can create a fixed terminal that opens up at boot and that will be located in a specific x + y position and with a fixed size. By digging around the forum I found two methods of achieving this: One was explained [in this forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613973/how-can-i-start-up-an-application-with-a-pre-defined-window-size-and-position), which works with a bash Script that must be run at startup-applications settings.

My idea was to add **neofetch** in that terminal and I have Zero to no-knowledge about scrip files and commands so I wasn't able that every time that the terminal was open neofetch would start up. I tried to modify the script but had no success.

**THE SCRIPT**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import sys

app = sys.argv[1]

get = lambda x: subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", x]).decode("utf-8")
ws1 = get("wmctrl -lp"); t = 0
subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", app])

while t < 30:      
    ws2 = [w.split()[0:3] for w in get("wmctrl -lp").splitlines() if not w in ws1]
    procs = [[(p, w[0]) for p in get("ps -e ww").splitlines() \
              if app in p and w[2] in p] for w in ws2]
    if len(procs) > 0:
        w_id = procs[0][0][1]
        cmd1 = "wmctrl -ir "+w_id+" -b remove,maximized_horz"
        cmd2 = "wmctrl -ir "+w_id+" -b remove,maximized_vert"
        cmd3 = "xdotool windowsize --sync "+procs[0][0][1]+" "+sys.argv[4]+"% "+sys.argv[5]+"%"
        cmd4 = "xdotool windowmove "+procs[0][0][1]+" "+sys.argv[2]+" "+sys.argv[3]
        for cmd in [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3, cmd4]:   
            subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
        break
    time.sleep(0.5)
    t = t+1
```

Code provided by: [Jacob Vlijm](https://askubuntu.com/users/72216/jacob-vlijm)

The second option I had, which works in a way was to use the following command:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry 82x26+1190+32 -- bash -c "neofetch; read"
```

[My setup with neofetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76idc.jpg)

A added the **read** command at the end of the bash so the "bash input" would not appear, But I am trying to hide the **white blinking cursor** as an idea I was trying to make it so the neofetch program would be in a pause state so it would not end unless something. If the script ends then this white cursor will appear and I am so picky and I hate that. **I don't want to remove the white blinking cursor entirely** but just for that terminal. IS there a way to hide that cursor? Or is there a way I can modify the neofetch .conf settings so I can create a pause command?

Thanks!
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gnome-terminal, you should be able to set cvvis (cursor visible) and civis (cursor invisible).

```
$ tput civis ## turn cursor off
$ tput cvvis ## turn curson on
```

Comment: WIll that command disable cursor entirely? or it will be just for one terminal

Comment: Is fixed!! I usedL gnome-terminal --geometry 82x26+1190+32 -- bash -c "neofetch; tput civis; read" and it worked!

Comment: @nickcrv06 Please "accept" this question if it worked for you: click the checkmark next to the question.